# I have a problem with adding elements to my page after click - "Undefined", what I need to do?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning JS and I don't know what to do with this problem.
A function must return something? If yes, what does it need to return?

It is a part of my js:

```
const workExamplesAdding = (htmlFirstText, htmlSecondText) => {
htmlFirstText += '<img src="/images/your_img_here1.png" alt="Example of our work" class="work-examples__item-img"><div class="work-examples__item-img--overlay"><a href="#" class="work-examples__item-link"><i class="far fa-eye"></i></a></div>';
htmlSecondText += '<img src="/images/your_img_here2.png" alt="Example of our work" class="work-examples__item-img"><div class="work-examples__item-img--overlay"><a href="#" class="work-examples__item-link"><i class="far fa-eye"></i></a></div>';

document.getElementById("work-examples__item--afterClick").innerHTML = htmlFirstText;
document.getElementById("work-examples__item--afterClick2").innerHTML = htmlSecondText;
document.getElementById("work-examples__item--afterClick3").innerHTML = htmlFirstText;
document.getElementById("work-examples__item--afterClick4").innerHTML = htmlSecondText;
document.getElementById("work-examples__item--afterClick5").innerHTML = htmlFirstText;
document.getElementById("work-examples__item--afterClick6").innerHTML = htmlSecondText;
document.getElementById("work-examples__item--afterClick7").innerHTML = htmlFirstText;
document.getElementById("work-examples__item--afterClick8").innerHTML = htmlSecondText;};
```

It is must look like this (without undefined):

[image: screenshotOfGoodVariant]

But it looks awful with undefined:

[image: screenshotOfBadVariant]

I can not give you html code, because Stack Overflow is warning that there is too much code.

Calling function:

```
const btnClick = (elementIsClicked, element) => {
  elementIsClicked = false;

  function clickHandler() {
    if (elementIsClicked = true) {
      showText();
      workExamplesAdding();
    } else {
      alert("Error");
    };
  };

  // grab a reference to your element
  element = document.getElementById('load-work-examples-btn'); 
  // associate the function above with the click event
  element.addEventListener('click', clickHandler); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You should learn how to use [F12 tools](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46dMldDhOOQ) and how to [debug](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) your JavaScript code

Comment: How do you call the `workExamplesAdding` function? It seems that you are passing no arguments...

Comment: If you don't pass a value to a parameter, it will be `undefined`. So you simply need to check if this is the case and in that case set it to an empty string. Or you can add a [default parameter value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Wow, problem was just in "htmlFirstText += ..." I did "htmlFirstText = ..." and it works!